# How can I read a text file greater than 5mb from android raw folder?

Tags: android, file, text, dictionary

I am creating a android app board game that a a dictionary text file that is around 5mb, How can I read this file from the raw or assets folder?

Anytime I try to search the dictionary I get a NullPointerException.

Any suggestions on reading and splitting large dictionary files would be helpful.

Comment: Raw asset have a size limitation of 1MB uncompressed. What format is your file in? If it's text-based, consider putting it into a sqlite/FTS table and have sqlite manage memory and indices for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Are You Running your App in Android Version below 2.2..
if yes then there is a limitation of 1MB max in Assets 
or Raw Folder..but in later version there is no restriction 
like this..so if you are able to run your code in later version
then that might be the ISSUE..i it does'nt show Nullpointer 
Exception ,It show Unable To compress large Data..kind of 
Exception... if this is the your can simply resolve this by
changing it to already Compress Format..these are Some Alredy 
Compressed Formet DVM Does'nt compress these formet..and you 
can use it,if it is Greater than !MB..
```

> ```
> static const char* kNoCompressExt[] = {
> ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif",
> ".wav", ".mp2", ".mp3", ".ogg", ".aac",
> ".mpg", ".mpeg", ".mid", ".midi", ".smf", ".jet",
> ".rtttl", ".imy", ".xmf", ".mp4", ".m4a",
> ".m4v", ".3gp", ".3gpp", ".3g2", ".3gpp2",
> ".amr", ".awb", ".wma", ".wmv"
> ```
>
> };      So Just Change your File Extention .txt to .jet....Resolved..:-)